# Rendering HTML from a job onto a page in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, rails-activejob, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am looking to create a job that renders a partial asynchronously once I gather selected resources from a backend database. I am doing this because the data I am fetching takes a long time to get, and I'd like to be able to display this data once it is received. Right now my code looks like this for the job:

```
class CommentsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as: default
  def perform(commenter_company)
   @comments = Comment.where(company: commenter_company)
   @html = CommentsController.render partial: "comments", assigns {comments: @comments }
  end
end
```

I already have the _comments.html.erb partial set up. I also have the queue adapter set to async so this job is indeed running in the background and finishes after the page is loaded.

I am successfully able to get the html and set it to the @html instance variable in the job.

My question is: how can I get this @html content onto the page that has already rendered? Can this be done from within the job, or do I need to use ActionCable/websockets to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like something you should use javascript for.  I am pretty sure to show the partial you will need either a hard refresh or some type of JS.

Comment: You will have to implement some caching. What you're trying to do is warming up th cache. See Russia doll caching with rails

Comment: Thanks guys. I would prefer to not have to do a refresh and display the data once it is available in ruby, but I understand that pushing to the client cant be done the way I have it set up. Also, wouldn't using a cache not work without a page refresh anyway?

Comment: I implemented this a few weeks back. Just push the data back to the client using ActionCable.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use ActionCable and use ajax to render the partial with js.erb when you receive a broadcasted message. i.e. in your /assets/javascript/channels/comments.js:

```
this.App = {};

App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

App.comments = App.cable.subscriptions.create('CommentsChannel', {
  received: function(data) {
    this.renderComments(data);
  },

  renderComments: function(data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/comments/update_comments"
      data: { data: data } // Depending on how you structure the data you received
    });
  }
});
```

In your comments controller you can do whatever you need in the /comments/update_comments method with the data you received so it will affect the partial you render. Lets say that it will just refresh @comments. Then use this update_comments.js.erb in your view files and it will refresh your partial in a given html element:

```
//app/views/comments/update_comments.js.erb
$('#comments_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments') %>");
```

Your partial may be something like:

```
<!-- app/views/comments/_comments.html.erb -->
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.user %>: <%= @comment.message %></p>
<% end %>
```

Hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast(
  "comments_#{@comment.id}_channel",
  view: ApplicationController.render(
    partial: 'comments/commment',
    locals: { comment: @comment }
  )
)
```

And in the js

```
App.comments = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
  {channel: 'CommentsChannel', id: comment_id }, {
  received: function(data) {
     $('#comments').append(data.view);
  },
```